# Entity Framework Change database type without recompile SqlCompact

Tags: database, configuration, entity-framework-4.1, edmx, dbcontext

I want to change the Database on which the entity Framework connects.
Within the same database type, everything works fine and i only have to change the connectionstring.

But when changing between SqlCompact and SqlServer this won't work because there are differences in the Schema files.

Currently I've one Project with the EDMX Files, One with the DbContext and DBSet (including the generated entitied) and multiple assemblies which are using the DBContext and DbSet to connect to the databases.

What is the best way to make the database (and also dbType including Schemas) interchangeable without needing a recompile ?

Comment: What happens when you use DbContext(String) function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.103).aspx?